# A problem of differential equations with invariant subspace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Thank you for your help in solving the following exercise

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be an operator that leaves a invariant subspace $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the solution of ${x}'=Ax$. If $x\left ( t_{0} \right )\in E$ for some $t_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$, show that $x\left ( t \right )\in E$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

One question

The exponential of a square matrix can also be defined as?

$e^{tA}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{j=0}^{n }\frac{t^{j}A^{j}}{j!}$

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the IVP is
$$
x(t)=e^{(t-t_0)A}x(t_0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t-t_0)^n}{n!}A^nx(t_0).
$$
But, $A^nx_0$ belongs to the invariant subspace of $A$, and so does the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t-t_0)^n}{n!}A^nx(t_0)$, since finite-dimensional spaces are closed.